# Edge NGram with phrase matching

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-query

I need to autocomplete [phrases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/phrase-matching.html). For example, when I search *"dementia in alz"*, I want to get *"dementia in alzheimer's"*.

For this, I configured [Edge NGram tokenizer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html). I tried both `edge_ngram_analyzer` and `standard` as the analyzer in the query body. Nevertheless, I can't get results when I'm trying to match a phrase.

What am I doing wrong?

My query:

```
{
  "query":{
    "multi_match":{
      "query":"dementia in alz",
      "type":"phrase",
      "analyzer":"edge_ngram_analyzer",
      "fields":["_all"]
    }
  }
}
```

My mappings:

```
...
"type" : {
  "_all" : {
    "analyzer" : "edge_ngram_analyzer",
    "search_analyzer" : "standard"
  },
  "properties" : {
    "field" : {
      "type" : "string",
      "analyzer" : "edge_ngram_analyzer",
      "search_analyzer" : "standard"
    },
...
"settings" : {
  ...
  "analysis" : {
    "filter" : {
      "stem_possessive_filter" : {
        "name" : "possessive_english",
        "type" : "stemmer"
      }
    },
    "analyzer" : {
      "edge_ngram_analyzer" : {
        "filter" : [ "lowercase" ],
        "tokenizer" : "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
      }
    },
    "tokenizer" : {
      "edge_ngram_tokenizer" : {
        "token_chars" : [ "letter", "digit", "whitespace" ],
        "min_gram" : "2",
        "type" : "edgeNGram",
        "max_gram" : "25"
      }
    }
  }
  ...
```

My documents:

```
{
  "_score": 1.1152233, 
  "_type": "Diagnosis", 
  "_id": "AVZLfHfBE5CzEm8aJ3Xp", 
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2016-08-02T13:40:48.665Z", 
    "type": "Diagnosis", 
    "Document_ID": "Diagnosis_1400541", 
    "Diagnosis": "F00.0 -  Dementia in Alzheimer's disease with early onset", 
    "@version": "1", 
  }, 
  "_index": "carenotes"
}, 
{
  "_score": 1.1152233, 
  "_type": "Diagnosis", 
  "_id": "AVZLfICrE5CzEm8aJ4Dc", 
  "_source": {
    "@timestamp": "2016-08-02T13:40:51.240Z", 
    "type": "Diagnosis", 
    "Document_ID": "Diagnosis_1424351", 
    "Diagnosis": "F00.1 -  Dementia in Alzheimer's disease with late onset", 
    "@version": "1", 
  }, 
  "_index": "carenotes"
}
```

Analysis of the *"dementia in alzheimer"* phrase:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "end_offset": 2, 
      "token": "de", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 0
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 3, 
      "token": "dem", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 1
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 4, 
      "token": "deme", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 2
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 5, 
      "token": "demen", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 3
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 6, 
      "token": "dement", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 4
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 7, 
      "token": "dementi", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 5
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 8, 
      "token": "dementia", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 6
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 9, 
      "token": "dementia ", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 7
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 10, 
      "token": "dementia i", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 8
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 11, 
      "token": "dementia in", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 9
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 12, 
      "token": "dementia in ", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 10
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 13, 
      "token": "dementia in a", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 11
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 14, 
      "token": "dementia in al", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 12
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 15, 
      "token": "dementia in alz", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 13
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 16, 
      "token": "dementia in alzh", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 14
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 17, 
      "token": "dementia in alzhe", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 15
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 18, 
      "token": "dementia in alzhei", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 16
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 19, 
      "token": "dementia in alzheim", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 17
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 20, 
      "token": "dementia in alzheime", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 18
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 21, 
      "token": "dementia in alzheimer", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 19
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use query_string instead of multi_match? Do let me know if it solves your problem.

Comment: The `query_string` searches in the `_all` field by default. So, it is the same as I do here with `multi_match` and `"fields": ["_all"]`. Nevertheless, I tried it, no success. I used the following query `{'query': {'query_string': {'query': 'dementia in alzh', 'phrase_slop': 0}}}`

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Many thanks to [rendel](https://github.com/rendel) who helped me to find the right solution!

*The solution of Andrei Stefan is not optimal.*

Why? First, the absence of the lowercase filter in the search analyzer makes search inconvenient; the case must be matched strictly. A custom analyzer with `lowercase` filter is needed instead of `"analyzer": "keyword"`.

Second, the **analysis part is wrong**!
During index time a string "*F00.0 -  Dementia in Alzheimer's disease with early onset*" is analyzed by `edge_ngram_analyzer`. With this analyzer, we have the following array of dictionaries as the analyzed string:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "end_offset": 2, 
      "token": "f0", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 0
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 3, 
      "token": "f00", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 1
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 6, 
      "token": "0 ", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 4, 
      "position": 2
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 9, 
      "token": "  ", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 3
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 10, 
      "token": "  d", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 4
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 11, 
      "token": "  de", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 5
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 12, 
      "token": "  dem", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 6
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 13, 
      "token": "  deme", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 7
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 14, 
      "token": "  demen", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 8
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 15, 
      "token": "  dement", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 9
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 16, 
      "token": "  dementi", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 10
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 17, 
      "token": "  dementia", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 11
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 18, 
      "token": "  dementia ", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 12
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 19, 
      "token": "  dementia i", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 13
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 20, 
      "token": "  dementia in", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 14
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 21, 
      "token": "  dementia in ", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 15
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 22, 
      "token": "  dementia in a", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 16
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 23, 
      "token": "  dementia in al", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 17
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 24, 
      "token": "  dementia in alz", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 18
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 25, 
      "token": "  dementia in alzh", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 19
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 26, 
      "token": "  dementia in alzhe", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 20
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 27, 
      "token": "  dementia in alzhei", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 21
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 28, 
      "token": "  dementia in alzheim", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 22
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 29, 
      "token": "  dementia in alzheime", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 23
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 30, 
      "token": "  dementia in alzheimer", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 7, 
      "position": 24
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 33, 
      "token": "s ", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 25
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 34, 
      "token": "s d", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 26
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 35, 
      "token": "s di", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 27
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 36, 
      "token": "s dis", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 28
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 37, 
      "token": "s dise", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 29
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 38, 
      "token": "s disea", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 30
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 39, 
      "token": "s diseas", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 31
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 40, 
      "token": "s disease", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 32
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 41, 
      "token": "s disease ", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 33
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 42, 
      "token": "s disease w", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 34
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 43, 
      "token": "s disease wi", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 35
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 44, 
      "token": "s disease wit", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 36
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 45, 
      "token": "s disease with", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 37
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 46, 
      "token": "s disease with ", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 38
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 47, 
      "token": "s disease with e", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 39
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 48, 
      "token": "s disease with ea", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 40
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 49, 
      "token": "s disease with ear", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 41
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 50, 
      "token": "s disease with earl", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 42
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 51, 
      "token": "s disease with early", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 43
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 52, 
      "token": "s disease with early ", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 44
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 53, 
      "token": "s disease with early o", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 45
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 54, 
      "token": "s disease with early on", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 46
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 55, 
      "token": "s disease with early ons", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 47
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 56, 
      "token": "s disease with early onse", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 31, 
      "position": 48
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the whole string tokenized with token size from 2 to 25 characters. The string is tokenized in a linear way together with all spaces and position incremented by one for every new token.

There are several problems with it:

1. The `edge_ngram_analyzer` produced **unuseful tokens** which will never be searched for, for example: "*0* ", "  ", "  *d*", "*s d*", "*s disease w*" etc.
2. Also, **it didn't produce** a lot of **useful tokens** that could be used, for example: "*disease*", "*early onset*" etc. There will be 0 results if you try to search for any of these words.
3. Notice, the last token is "*s disease with early onse*". Where is the final "*t*"? Because of the `"max_gram" : "25"` we “**lost**” some text in all fields. You can't search for this text anymore because there are no tokens for it.
4. The `trim` filter only obfuscates the problem filtering extra spaces when it could be done by a tokenizer.
5. The `edge_ngram_analyzer` increments the position of each token which is problematic for positional queries such as phrase queries. One should use the `edge_ngram_filter` instead that will **preserve the position** of the token when generating the ngrams.

## The optimal solution.

The mappings settings to use:

```
...
"mappings": {
    "Type": {
       "_all":{
          "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer", 
          "search_analyzer": "keyword_analyzer"
        }, 
        "properties": {
          "Field": {
            "search_analyzer": "keyword_analyzer",
             "type": "string",
             "analyzer": "edge_ngram_analyzer"
          },
...
...
"settings": {
   "analysis": {
      "filter": {
         "english_poss_stemmer": {
            "type": "stemmer",
            "name": "possessive_english"
         },
         "edge_ngram": {
           "type": "edgeNGram",
           "min_gram": "2",
           "max_gram": "25",
           "token_chars": ["letter", "digit"]
         }
      },
      "analyzer": {
         "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
           "filter": ["lowercase", "english_poss_stemmer", "edge_ngram"],
           "tokenizer": "standard"
         },
         "keyword_analyzer": {
           "filter": ["lowercase", "english_poss_stemmer"],
           "tokenizer": "standard"
         }
      }
   }
}
...
```

Look at the analysis:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "end_offset": 5, 
      "token": "f0", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 0
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 5, 
      "token": "f00", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 0
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 5, 
      "token": "f00.", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 0
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 5, 
      "token": "f00.0", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 0, 
      "position": 0
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 17, 
      "token": "de", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 9, 
      "position": 2
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 17, 
      "token": "dem", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 9, 
      "position": 2
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 17, 
      "token": "deme", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 9, 
      "position": 2
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 17, 
      "token": "demen", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 9, 
      "position": 2
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 17, 
      "token": "dement", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 9, 
      "position": 2
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 17, 
      "token": "dementi", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 9, 
      "position": 2
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 17, 
      "token": "dementia", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 9, 
      "position": 2
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 20, 
      "token": "in", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 18, 
      "position": 3
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 32, 
      "token": "al", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 21, 
      "position": 4
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 32, 
      "token": "alz", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 21, 
      "position": 4
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 32, 
      "token": "alzh", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 21, 
      "position": 4
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 32, 
      "token": "alzhe", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 21, 
      "position": 4
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 32, 
      "token": "alzhei", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 21, 
      "position": 4
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 32, 
      "token": "alzheim", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 21, 
      "position": 4
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 32, 
      "token": "alzheime", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 21, 
      "position": 4
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 32, 
      "token": "alzheimer", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 21, 
      "position": 4
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 40, 
      "token": "di", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 33, 
      "position": 5
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 40, 
      "token": "dis", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 33, 
      "position": 5
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 40, 
      "token": "dise", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 33, 
      "position": 5
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 40, 
      "token": "disea", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 33, 
      "position": 5
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 40, 
      "token": "diseas", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 33, 
      "position": 5
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 40, 
      "token": "disease", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 33, 
      "position": 5
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 45, 
      "token": "wi", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 41, 
      "position": 6
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 45, 
      "token": "wit", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 41, 
      "position": 6
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 45, 
      "token": "with", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 41, 
      "position": 6
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 51, 
      "token": "ea", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 46, 
      "position": 7
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 51, 
      "token": "ear", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 46, 
      "position": 7
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 51, 
      "token": "earl", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 46, 
      "position": 7
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 51, 
      "token": "early", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 46, 
      "position": 7
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 57, 
      "token": "on", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 52, 
      "position": 8
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 57, 
      "token": "ons", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 52, 
      "position": 8
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 57, 
      "token": "onse", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 52, 
      "position": 8
    }, 
    {
      "end_offset": 57, 
      "token": "onset", 
      "type": "word", 
      "start_offset": 52, 
      "position": 8
    }
  ]
}
```

On index time a text is tokenized by `standard` tokenizer, then separate words are filtered by `lowercase`, `possessive_english` and `edge_ngram` filters. **Tokens are produced only for words**. 
On search time a text is tokenized by `standard` tokenizer, then separate words are filtered by `lowercase` and `possessive_english`. The searched words are matched against the tokens which had been created during the index time.

Thus we make the incremental search possible!

Now, because we do ngram on separate words, we can even execute queries like

```
{
  'query': {
    'multi_match': {
      'query': 'dem in alzh',  
      'type': 'phrase', 
      'fields': ['_all']
    }
  }
}
```

and get correct results.

No text is "lost", everything is searchable and there is no need to deal with spaces by `trim` filter anymore.

Comment: I wouldn't have had time for such an elaborate solution, but I appreciate you took the time to report back your findings. At least, I was able to help you spot an initial issue. Cheers!

Comment: Many thanks @trex, I had the same requirements, just set up this method.

Comment: There is a syntax problem in mappings braces the solution is not working for us ???

Comment: @tina what is your Elasticsearch version? What is the error? What is your mapping?

Comment: @trex my elastic search version is 5.5.2 and the mapping shown in the above answer doesn't close all braces

Answer (score 9):

I believe your query is wrong: while you need nGrams at indexing time, you don't need them at search time. At search time you need the text to be as "fixed" as possible.
Try this query instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "  dementia in alz",
      "analyzer": "keyword",
      "fields": [
        "_all"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

You notice two whitespaces before `dementia`. Those are accounted for by your analyzer from the text. To get rid of those you need the `trim` token_filter:

```
   "edge_ngram_analyzer": {
      "filter": [
        "lowercase","trim"
      ],
      "tokenizer": "edge_ngram_tokenizer"
    }
```

And then this query will work (no whitespaces before `dementia`):

```
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "query": "dementia in alz",
      "analyzer": "keyword",
      "fields": [
        "_all"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Also, I repeated the test with the `lowercase` filter adding the following analyzer to the existing mappings `"keyword_analyzer" : {"filter" : [ "lowercase" ], "tokenizer" : "keyword"}`. And the query was `{'query': {'multi_match': {'query': 'dementia in alz', 'analyzer': 'keyword_analyzer', 'fields': ['_all']}}}`. No success :-(

Comment: I need to see a complete document to test against and the **complete** mapping of the index. Use gist please.

Comment: You can use these [two documents](https://gist.github.com/SergeyBondarenko/934c61cf7fae7ade07ce58f8e59c6b7f)

Comment: And what's the text that you want to match?

Comment: I want to match the text in the _Diagnosis_ field.

Comment: And you want to do it on `_all` or that was just one of your tests?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to give you all you asked for. Look at the [index mappings](https://gist.github.com/SergeyBondarenko/349ddf0cc599ee092f83b908110ec016) I left only the `Diagnosis` document type.

Comment: I have around 300 document types. `Diagnosis` is one of them. I need to find all documents with _Dementia in Alzheimer's_ text.

Comment: I slightly updated my query. Try that and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Also, there are other types of documents with _... Dementia in Alzheimer's ..._ text.

Comment: Yeah!!! It works! Thank you. But how did you find it? Is there some specific key to the `_analyze` API method?

Comment: In ES 2.x I used the following query to look at the `_all` field and its terms: `{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "println doc['_all']; return true;"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`