# How to do Incremental/Search as you type full text search on 5 million records sets using Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, search, full-text-search, n-gram, incremental-search

I m using elastic search on a huge dataset of all wikipedia article names they are approx 5 million in numbers database field name is articlenames

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/index_wiki_articlenames/" -d'
{
   "settings":{
      "analysis":{
         "filter":{
            "nGram_filter":{
               "type":"edgeNGram",
               "min_gram":1,    
               "max_gram":20,
               "token_chars":[
                  "letter",
                  "digit",
                  "punctuation",
                  "symbol"
               ]
            }
         },
         "tokenizer":{
            "edge_ngram_tokenizer":{
               "type":"edgeNGram",
               "min_gram":"1",
               "max_gram":"20",
               "token_chars":[
                  "letter",
                  "digit"
               ]
            }                                                                                                                   
         },
         "analyzer":{
            "nGram_analyzer":{
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"edge_ngram_tokenizer",
               "filter":[
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         },
         "whitespace_analyzer": {
               "type": "custom",
               "tokenizer": "whitespace",
               "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{                                                                         
      "name":{
         "properties":{
            "articlenames":{
               "type":"text",
               "analyzer":"nGram_analyzer"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Referencing these links to solve my problem as well but in vain

[Edge NGram with phrase matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38848121/edge-ngram-with-phrase-matching/38893908#38893908)

https://hackernoon.com/elasticsearch-building-autocomplete-functionality-494fcf81a7cf

my aim is to get results like below for input query of "sachin t"

```
sachin tendulkar
sachin tendulkar centuries
sachin tejas 
sachin top 60 quotes
sachin talwalkar
sachin tawade
sachin taps
```

and for query of "sachin te"

```
sachin tendulkar
sachin tendulkar centuries
sachin tejas
```

and for query of "sachin ta"

```
sachin talwalkar
sachin tawade
sachin taps
```

and for query of "sachin ten"

```
sachin tendulkar
sachin tendulkar centuries
```

Remember the dataset is huge some article names and words can have special characters and words  like  "Bronisław-Komorowski"

I am able to get output for smaller dataset up to 100 thousand records but as soon as my dataset changes to 0.5 to 5 million records
I am unable to get output

and my query is

```
http://127.0.0.1:9200/index_wiki_articlenames/_search?&q=articlenames:sachin-t+articlenames:sachin-t.*&filter_path=hits.hits._source.articlenames&size=50
```

Comment: What is your query?

Comment: Just added comment at the end of the post

Comment: About the query, better use the query DSL (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_introducing_the_query_language.html) instead of the search API.

Comment: It seems like you are trying to implement auto suggest/complete. Have you looked at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have an answer to your question though!

Comment: What do you mean by `as soon as my dataset changes to 0.5 to 5 million records I am unable to get output`? What happens then? ES dies? Takes too much time to return anything?

Comment: Thanks Andrei for the replly I meant I m not getting desired output in the sequence of sachin tendulkar,
sachin tendulkar centuries, sachin tejas ... As soon as the dataset increases I m getting output as sachin abbas,sachin borke,sachin jai,sachin tendulkar which is not the desired output sequence for input query of "sachin t"

Comment: @AndreiStefan did you understand my doubt ??

Comment: I did, but now I don't have time to test and look into this and see why it's matching something else. The guess is that when the number of docs increases, all the bits that go into calculating a score (relevance scoring) "level out". Basically, the more docs you have, the more relevant the score is. At this point you'd probably need a way to boost those documents that are relevant from your point of view. But you might be doing something wrong in your search... but I have no time to dig into that. And the link you reference is using `multi_match`, you are doing it differently ;-).

Comment: Thanks a lot @AndreiStefan once you are free please do help meanwhile will keep trying from my side as well

Comment: I am not sure of ES performance capabilities for 5 mil records, but you may want to look into ES data sharding

Answer (score 0):

You should try these settings:

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/index_wiki_articlenames/" -d'
{
   "settings":{
      "analysis":{
         "tokenizer":{
            "edge_ngram_tokenizer":{
               "type":"edgeNGram",
               "min_gram":"1",
               "max_gram":"20",
               "token_chars":[
                  "letter",
                  "digit"
               ]
            }                                                                                                                   
         },
         "analyzer":{
            "nGram_analyzer":{
               "type":"custom",
               "tokenizer":"edge_ngram_tokenizer",
               "filter":[
                  "lowercase",
                  "asciifolding"
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "mappings":{                                                                         
      "name":{
         "properties":{
            "articlenames":{
               "type":"text",
               "analyzer":"nGram_analyzer",
               "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}'
```

Also when querying try this query:

```
GET my_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "articlenames": {
        "query": "Sachin T", 
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late, but anybody who's looking for a solution for this can try this query. Mapping & Index is correct. Seems to be missing and operator in query section.

```
GET index_wiki_articlenames/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "articlenames": {
        "query": "sachin ten", 
        "operator": "and"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This results in

```
sachin tendulkar
sachin tendulkar centuries
```